# how to link pages to menu dynamically in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have page and menu mysql database table, how do i link pages with menu and submenus in php ? pls help. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `menu` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `longdesc` text NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
 `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



CREATE TABLE `pages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `content` text NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Does not make any sense more elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you have a menu-table that has all your menu items and you want to link them to a page, assuming that if you have a page-id you can then easily load that page.

Not all pages have a corresponding menu-item, but all menu-items have a page (where they link to).

I'd say you want to add a "pageId" field to your menu table. Indexed, not unique, maybe allowing NULL for the parent (i don't know what that is for, but that might be a header-type thing without a link?).

You're on MyISAM, so no constraints possible, that leaves adding this:

```
 `pageId` int(11) NULL
```